# Using Selenium IDE tool can we check the font color and font size or CSS values of the web element?

Tags: selenium-ide

For example, I have to check Category text font color and font size showing below code; how to identify the CSS value using Selenium IDE tool?

```html
<div class="featured">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="col-md-8 latest">
          <h4>Category</h4>
     </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try execute script function. See my example below:

[image]

Here is test output:

[image]

Inside `getComputedStype` you need to use JS way to look up the element you need and then invoke `getPropertyValue` with the value you would like to assert. Being saved to a variable (in my case it is `${WDTH}`) you will be able to test your property for a specific value.